# How do boolean operations work with parentheses in python 2.7?

Tags: python, python-2.7, logic, boolean-expression

Found this little oddity while playing around.

```
>>> 'Hello' == ('Hello' or 'World')
True
>>> 'Hello' == ('World' or 'Hello')
False
>>> 'Hello' == ('Hello' and 'World')
False
>>> 'Hello' == ('World' and 'Hello')
True
```

Is there some trick to this logic that I'm not getting? Why is the order of the strings the determining factor of these queries? Should I not be using parentheses at all? Why does changing to "and" flip the outputs?

Thanks a buncharooni.

Comment: Just type `'Hello' or 'World'` into the interactive prompt and see what happens.

Comment: `>>> 'Hello'` returns `'Hello'`. I copied this straight out of the UNIX shell.

Comment: Just type `'Hello' or 'World'` into the interactive prompt and see what happens.

Comment: Why all the downvotes? True, this is probably answered elsewhere, but it's still a surprising bit of behavior for someone unfamiliar with the language, and the question itself is worded well enough.

Comment: Okay, so I reread your comment, facepalmed, then tried it out. So `or` returns the first value and `and` returns the last value? And `or` is 'stronger' than `and`? Because I then tried this out:
`'Hello' or 'World' and '!'` and it returned `'Hello'`

Comment: The behavior is documented here https://docs.python.org/release/2.5.2/lib/boolean.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Python, all objects may be considered "truthy" or "falsy". Python uses this fact to create a sneaky shortcut when evaluating boolean logic. If it encounters a value that would allow the logic to "short-circuit", such as a `True` at the beginning of an `or`, or a `False` at the start of an `and`, it simply *returns the definitive value*. This works because that value *itself* evaluates appropriately to be truthy or falsy, and therefore whatever boolean context it's being used in continues to function as expected. In fact, such operations *always* just return the first value they encounter that allows them to fully evaluate the expression (even if it's the last value).

```
# "short-circuit" behavior
>>> 2 or 0
2
>>> 0 and 2
0

# "normal" (fully-evaluated) behavior
>>> 'cat' and 'dog'
'dog'
>>> 0 or 2
2
```

Answer (score 2):

- `x or y` returns the first operand if its truthy, otherwise returns
  the second operand.
- `x and y` returns the first operand if its
  falsey, otherwise returns the second operand.

For what it looks like you're trying to accomplish you may prefer this:

```
'Hello' in ['Hello', 'World']
```

Comment: Thanks, that is what I was doing (using lists) but I was curious so I poked around. I guess SO thinks this is a pretty dumb question, at -2.

Comment: Not dumb, but there are already many, many questions dealing with the same issue, so it does show a certain lack of research before asking.

Comment: @eli_dink I didn't down-vote your question, but *many* questions I see on the python tag can be answered by typing a few things into the interactive prompt. That, and the built-in help make python quite easy to learn and debug.